# Запись/Чтение строкового массива в Java, Android

Tags: java, android

Есть строковый массив test, нужно сохранить его в папке на телефоне, чтобы его можно было увидеть из проводника. А потом считать его из папки Download

Comment: а в чем, собственно , вопрос? что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович Не получается найти информацию о том, как  сохранить строковый массив в папку, а потом его прочитать, но сохранённый файл должен быть виден из проводника

Comment: гуглите в сторону записи файлов в external storage, пытайтесь закодить, будут трудности - показывайте, подскажем

Comment: @SviatVolkov Нашёл код сохранения массива байтов, но есть ошибки, [скрин](https://pp.userapi.com/c639530/v639530850/5b22b/wBvYYg_WaSo.jpg)
. Можно ли его изменить для строк?